# Can I run build for entire PR, not only batch of commits?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cicd

Is there any option to trigger build ONLY for entire pull request (only on merge)? I could not find any info about that option, in triggers settings there is only "Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer" option. Will triggering on "Merged" comment works?

I tried to create a trigger but there's no option for this.

In my team we're using teamcity 2020.2.4.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html ?

Comment: @Peska yes, but it still starts two separate builds if there are two different commiters. I don't know how to make it works. I have pull requests turned on and configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit your branch spec to only watch master, it will only trigger when commits are made to master. Given that you are performing PRs from feature branches to master, a build set up to only trigger (limited by the branch filter in the CVS root) on new changes, will only trigger once the merge commit (or any other commits made to master) have been made.

The workflow you describe puts some requirements and limitations on the process that you work with and disallowing commits to master from everyone except the build system / VCS is one such rule you could set in place to achieve this.

The other setting you mention, "Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer", will let TeamCity bundle together the changes included in a build, if the commits come in within the allowed time limit (defaults to 1 minute, if I remember right). If this setting is not enabled, all commits - even those which come in one after the other within a very short time frame - will trigger a new, separate build.
I'd generally advise to enable that option and set the timeframe to 1 minute or whichever suits your team the best.